# inequality $|x + 3\eta^2| \geq |x| + |\eta|^2$

Tags: analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, triangle-inequality, oscillatory-integral

I'm learning the basics of Fourier Analysis. Reading a book, I've found this inequality:
" If $x\geq -3$ and $|\eta | >2$ we have $|x + 3\eta^2| \geq |x| + |\eta|^2$. I've tried to solve  this inequality applying triangle one but I failed. Can you help me, please?

Comment: The integral is trivially true when $x \ge 0$, so you may as well restrict yourself to $0 > x \ge -3$.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, but how can I get the remaining part?

Comment: Note that under your hypothesis, this inequality is equivalent to $x+3\eta^2\ge|x|+\eta^2$.

Comment: What book , what page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comments of @Gregory, it suffices to consider $-3<x<0$. In that case
$0<|x|=-x<3$.

Since $\eta^{2}>4>|x|$, adding $\eta^{2}-|x|$ to both sides we get
$$2\eta^{2}>2|x|\Longrightarrow 3\eta^{2}-|x|>\eta^{2}+|x|.$$
Observe that $$3\eta^{2}-|x|=|3\eta^{2}+x|,$$
when $x<0$.

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: And what if $|\eta|>1$? Does the inequality hold too? I cannot repeat the same argument in this case

Comment: No. Test the inequality for $x=-3$ and $\eta=3/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Under your hypothesis, the inequality you want to prove is equivalent to $$x+3\eta^2\ge|x|+\eta^2$$
i.e.
$$2\eta^2\ge|x|-x,$$
which is obvious if $x\ge0$, and is a consequence of $x+\eta^2>0$ if $x\le0$.